# Syntax-quote a macro argument?

Tags: clojure

I want to syntax-quote a passed argument to a macro, but I can't get my head around it. So given a macro `quote-it` and `<`, i would like to get

```
(quote-it <)
=> clojure.core/<
```

Neither works of the following:

```
(defmacro quote-it [a] `~a)
=> #'user/quote-it
(quote-it <)
=> #object[clojure.core$_LT_ 0x11c08900 "clojure.core$_LT_@11c08900"]

(defmacro quote-it [a] `'~a)
=> #'user/quote-it
(quote-it <)
=> <
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **resolve the symbol to a var** in the current namespace using the [clojure.core/resolve](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve) function. The var object contains the namespace and name of the original symbol. You can then construct a new symbol using these values and return it.

```
(defmacro quote-it [a]
  (let [r (resolve a)]
    `'~(symbol (str (:ns (meta r))) (str (:name (meta r))))))
```